# Why i can put nullable value with Mono.fromCalleable

Tags: java, kotlin, null, reactive, reactor

i wonder why i can do something like:

```
val ans = Mono.fromCallable { null }.block() 
Assert.assertEquals(null, ans)
```

and it succeed. I understood that in reactive programming we should not handle null values in the channels

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because it is OK to finish `Mono` with the `null`. In this case it moves directly to complete state with empty (null) content:

```
        T t = callable.call();
        if (t == null) {
            sds.onComplete();
        }
        else {
            sds.complete(t);
        }
```

Where:

```
@Override
public final void onComplete() {
    countDown();
}
```

And when you call that `block()`, you just get `null` `value` from the `Mono`.

The point is that nothing is going to be handled in the channels because the state is already `complete`. So, we go to the return `null` immediately.